# How to highlight important pages in glossaries page number list

Tags: formatting, page-numbering, glossaries, acronyms

In some books, the keywords page not only has a list of pages the keyword was referenced, it also bold or emphasize page numbers where the keyword was defined or explained. How do I do that with acronym option in glossaries?

With the MWE attached, the glossary page gives:

> Fft fast Fourier transform. 1–3

I would like something akin to:

> Fft fast Fourier transform. **2**, 1-3

or 1,**2**,3 or similar. The best idea is to have a user field say user6 with a user defined label link such that in the acronym definition:

```
\newacronym[sort=FFT,user6={\pageref{link:fft}}]{FFT}{\textsc{Fft}}{fast Fourier transform}
```

I presume it may be quite an undertaking?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries} 
\newacronym[sort=FFT]{FFT}{\textsc{Fft}}{fast Fourier transform}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\Ac{FFT} is widely used to compute Fourier transforms. For more information see p.\pageref{link:fft}
\newpage
\section{Fast Fourier Transform}\label{link:fft}
\Acf{FFT}, is a radix-2 algorithm implementing the discrete Fourier transform...........................................................%explanation
\newpage
\ac{FFT} %some other references
\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to just use the `format` key at the principle reference. Like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries} 
\newacronym[sort=FFT]{FFT}{\textsc{Fft}}{fast Fourier transform}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\Ac{FFT} is widely used to compute Fourier transforms. For more
information see p.\pageref{link:fft}
\newpage
\section{Fast Fourier Transform}\label{link:fft}
\Acf[format=hyperbf]{FFT}, is a radix-2 algorithm implementing the discrete Fourier
transform...........................................................%explanation
\newpage
\ac{FFT} %some other references
\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, and I think my status as top user of the [tag:glossaries] tag will soon be over. :-)

Comment: Ingenious! One small concern, how do I preserve the compatibility with `hyperref`? When I tried the above the `hyperref` link is not created at the bold page number

Comment: @MobiusPizza change `textbf` to `hyperbf` (I've edited the example to include `hyperref` and made this change.)

Comment: Sorry for necroing this, I realize that using this method generates duplicated page number such as 8, **8**. I guess there is no easy way round that unless manually changing all references text format to bf on p.8?

Comment: @MobiusPizza I don't think there is an easy way around this as there's no way of telling `makeindex` what to do with duplicate page numbers that have different formats. I usually use `\gls[format=hyperbf]` for the main reference and `\glsentrytext` for the neighbouring references. (Or `\ac[format=hyperbf]` and `\glsentryshort`.) The only alternative I can think of is to post-process the `.gls` or `.acr` file.