# Distinct formatted page numbers with glossaries and Xindy

Tags: formatting, glossaries, xindy

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78300/how-to-highlight-important-pages-in-glossaries-page-number-list), but using Xindy as a backend, not `makeindex`.

I am attempting to create an index using `glossaries`, and in this index some page numbers have a special meaning. These are therefore typeset in italic. Unfortunately, when the same item is referenced both with its special meaning and as a regular item, in that order, the page number in the index is not italic. The following MWE illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{test}{name={Test},description={\nopostdesc}}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
  \glsadd[format=hyperit]{test}
  \glsadd{test}
  \printglossary[style=index]
\end{document}
```

The result of this MWE is

[image: result of MWE]

while I would like the page number to be either italic (i.e., the formatted page number always has priority) or displayed once for each formatting. **Is this possible using Xindy as a backend?**

I did try a method in which I defined a fake counter for the special entries, thinking that this would result in separate entries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\newcounter{fakepage}
\GlsAddXdyCounters{fakepage}
\newglossaryentry{test}{name={Test},description={\nopostdesc}}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
  \setcounter{fakepage}{\thepage}
  \glsadd[format=hyperit,counter=fakepage]{test}
  \glsadd{test}
  \printglossary[style=index]
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this resulted in [wierd errors from Xindy](https://gist.github.com/4459009) and a result identical to that of the first MWE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to manually change the ordering of the defined attributes. If you look in the `.glo` file for your MWE, you should see the location attributes are `pageglsnumberformat` (the default format) and `pagehyperit` (the format used when you combine `format=hyperit` and `counter=page`):

```
(indexentry :tkey (("Test" "\\glossaryentryfield{test}{\\glsnamefont{Test}}{\\nopostdesc }{\\relax }") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pagehyperit" )
(indexentry :tkey (("Test" "\\glossaryentryfield{test}{\\glsnamefont{Test}}{\\nopostdesc }{\\relax }") ) :locref "{}{1}" :attr "pageglsnumberformat" )
```

The default `.xdy` file created by `glossaries` lists the `pageglsnumberformat` attribute before the `pagehyperit` attribute. This order needs to be swapped. There are two possibilities:

```
(define-attributes ( ("pagehyperit" "pageglsnumberformat")))
```

This will result in just one location using the `hyperit` format:

[image: Resulting image]

The second option is:

```
(define-attributes ( ("pagehyperit") ("pageglsnumberformat")))
```

This will result in two locations. The first using the `hyperit` format and the second location using the default `pageglsnumberformat` format:

[image: Resulting image]

Either way, if you manually edit the `.xdy` file you must add `\noist` to your document to prevent the `.xdy` file from being overridden:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{test}{name={Test},description={\nopostdesc}}
\noist
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
  \glsadd[format=hyperit]{test}
  \glsadd{test}
  \printglossary[style=index]
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to manually edit the `.xdy` file, you'll need to redefine some of `glossaries` internal commands.

First case: redefine `\@gls@addpredefinedattributes` to list the attributes in your desired order:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@gls@addpredefinedattributes}{%
  \GlsAddXdyAttribute{hyperit}
  \GlsAddXdyAttribute{glsnumberformat}
}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{test}{name={Test},description={\nopostdesc}}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
  \glsadd[format=hyperit]{test}
  \glsadd{test}
  \printglossary[style=index]
\end{document}
```

The second case is more complicated (`\string"` is used in case the double quote has been made active, e.g. via `ngerman`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@gls@addpredefinedattributes}{%
  \GlsAddXdyAttribute{hyperit}
  \GlsAddXdyAttribute{glsnumberformat}
}

\renewcommand*\@glsaddxdyattribute[2]{%
  \edef\@xdyattributes{\@xdyattributes) ^^J (\string"#1\string") ^^J
    (\string"#2#1\string"}%
  \expandafter\toks@\expandafter{\@xdylocref}%
  \edef\@xdylocref{\the\toks@ ^^J%
    (markup-locref
    :open \string"\string~n%
      \expandafter\string\csname glsX#2X#1\endcsname
      \string" ^^J
    :close \string"\string" ^^J
    :attr \string"#2#1\string")}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname glsX#2X#1\endcsname##1##2{%
     \setentrycounter[##1]{#2}\csname #1\endcsname{##2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newglossaryentry{test}{name={Test},description={\nopostdesc}}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
  \glsadd[format=hyperit]{test}
  \glsadd{test}
  \printglossary[style=index]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this possible to do without manually editing the `.xdy` file?